# How to make Excel Add-In only available for Windows and Online but not Mac

Tags: office365, office365api, office-js, office365-apps

I am building an Add-In for Excel that relies heavily on Ribbon Icon Commands.

I want to submit it into the Office Store, but the feedback I get is that they cannot accept it because it does not support Excel for Mac (which itself does not support Add-In Commands).

Is there a way to make the manifest only be accepted by Excel 2016 and Excel Online and not Excel for Mac?

I tried putting

```
<Requirements>
  <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
    <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.2"/>
  </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

into the manifest because I thought that Mac would not support it (according to https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/office-add-in-requirement-sets ) but apperently it does support it.

Answer (score 0):

At present, it is not able to specify the Office add-in for the specific platform. Base on my understanding, the office add-in is a technology which help us to develop cross platform add-in. We shouldn't care about which platform the users were using.

To make the specific API in Office add-in work properly, we can set the requirements. And if the API members are available, you can do a run time check if you like to provide additional functionality. Here is an helpful article about [Specify Office hosts and API requirements](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements).

Comment: So does this mean that you can't build and distribute and Add-In at this point that does rely on Add-In commands? It always has to work without commands, too?

Comment: No. we can make add-in available on all Office hosts and platforms, use runtime checks instead of the Requirements element. This way is also the Microsoft recommend at present. You can see the detail in the **note** section in the link of orignal post.